# MySQL replace part of string

Tags: mysql, string, sql-update

I have a varchar field with `latitude` values.
I would like to replace part of the string, the *"integer"* part,

for example:

```
7.215555
2.584555
23.154525
12.54836
44.124556
```

should change to:

```
20.215555
20.584555
20.154525
20.54836
20.124556
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 20 is a hardcoded string you want to replace with values before point you can do  so

```
UPDATE table 
SET latitude = CONCAT('20.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(latitude ,'.',-1))
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71d94/1)